# Mysql Where IN (query) doesn't work. here, query gives a string(example: 1,2,3)

Tags: mysql, performance-testing, query-performance

- table name table1,
- primary column column 1,
- column name column2,
- data in column2 '1,2,3' where column1=1.

Query:

```
select `id` 
from `table2` 
where `id` IN (select `column2` from `table1` where `column1`=1)
```

I found the following way to solve this till now,

1. I can run the subquery separately.
2. Use the `find_in_set()` function.

As `find_in_set` is non-sargable I was looking for a solution where I can do this within one query.

Comment: Can you explain with some data and expected output.?

Comment: Don't store comma-separated lists in a table column, normalize your data.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-sargable"?

Comment: In relational databases, a condition (or predicate) in a query is said to be sargable if the DBMS engine can take advantage of an index to speed up the execution of the query.
A query failing to be sargable is known as non-sargable query

Comment: can you give me the link of that question, you think it is duplicate to that?